# paypal token I'm given is invalid?

Tags: php, paypal

i'm using paypal's express checkout API in PHP, and the `SetExpressCheckout` operation works fine. But when paypal redirect's to my page that handles the `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` operation, it gives me a `10410: Invalid Token` error. I'm using the token they provide in the url, so what's the problem?

Here's the code i'm using:

```
$token = urldecode($this->params['url']['token']);
$req_str = 'USER=%s&PWD=%s&SIGNATURE=%s&VERSION=%s&METHOD=%s&TOKEN=%';
$req_query = sprintf($req_str, Configure::read('Paypal.username'), Configure::read('Paypal.password'), Configure::read('Paypal.signature'), "65.1", 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $token);
```

Comment: Have you tested whether `$token` actually  contains anything?

Comment: Yes it does. it has the correct token.

Comment: *facepalm* i can't believe i missed that!

Comment: Heh, that happens. You can consider deleting this question (seeing as it's very localized and unlikely to ever help anybody else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a `s` in

```
$req_str = 'USER=%s&PWD=%s&SIGNATURE=%s&VERSION=%s&METHOD=%s&TOKEN=%';
                                                           HERE ----^
```